# Google earth balloon not fully visible

Tags: kml, google-earth, google

When i load my KML on google earth, the balloon appears whole but when I embed on a webpage using the embedKML tool, the data in the balloon (In this case a table) appears to be cut. The close button is not showing. I have tried increasing width and height in the tool but there is no change.

[image: Image of my google earth after embedding it on a webpage]

Comment: you might have to create a slider control to view your content correctly - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465310/slider-inside-google-map-info-window

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the KML Reference. Balloon styling can be applied, see https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#balloonstyle

You can also specify CSS styling for balloon description text. See 
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#feature

Here's an example that combines Balloon Styles and CSS to control how balloons are displayed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202265/css-in-google-earth-plugin